# How can I detect when a scrollview has reached the bottom so that I can load more items into it?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a scrollview in my android application that I fill with Items from a database.  I start off with 20 items in it, but what I want to happen is for the scrollview to load more items when the user pulls the scrollview up when it is at the bottom.  I could override onDetectOverflow if it weren't private but I cannot so I can't figure out how to detect when the user is pulling the scrollview up.  There doesnt seem to be any onScroll Listener I can use so does anyone have a way I can detect this?

Comment: use a listview with endless scroll. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Comment: Any reason why you are using a ScrollView as opposed to a ListView? The ListView seems to be more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PullToRefresh listview for your requirement. It will load data for both scrollview up and scrollview down according to the user scrolling.. The following link provides the source of PullToRefresh listview

[PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

[AndroidPullToRefresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)

[PullToRefresh-ListView](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView)

Comment: I need to apply loadmore for scrollview, not listview. How to do that?